# why not show listbox items in wp8 using linq query

Tags: linq, windows-phone-8, listbox

when i run program, listbox not show nothing. 
please give me correct code.

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="MultiList" FontSize="26"   >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=id}" Width="150"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=project_id}"/>
                                <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="button"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtDay" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtTemp"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

//-------------------------

```
phoneDBContext db = new phoneDBContext("Data Source='appdata:/phoneDB.sdf'; File Mode = Read Write;");
    var q1 = from p in db.Projects
                         select p;

                MultiList1.ItemsSource = q1.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The first letter of each field  has to be uppercase.
I wasted one week time on this problem.
It shows a bug in the IntelliSense editor of Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.
I hope Microsoft will correct this problem.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="150"/>
```

Comment: Your answer to your own question is unclear.  If you would put more detail about what actually fixed your error then this answer will be of use to others who might have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try without "Path=". Example: Text="{Binding id}"